# Rails controller does not deliver email in test with ActiveMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rspec, actionmailer

We have a Rails controller that send email:

```
class UsersController
  def invite
    mail = WeeklyReport.weekly_report(current_user).deliver
    flash[:notice] = "Mail sent!"
    redirect_to controller: "partners", action: "index"
  end
end

class WeeklyReport < ActionMailer::Base
  def weekly_report(recipient)
    @data = recipient.data
    mail(:to => "#{recipient.name} <#{recipient.email}>", :subject => "Weekly report")
  end
end
```

When testing the controller manually, it is actually sending the email. But the controler test is failing:

```
it "should send mail" do
  get :invite

  response.should redirect_to "/partners/index"
  request.flash[:notice].should eql("Mail sent!")

  deliveries.size.should == 1 ### TEST FAILS HERE!

  last_email.subject.should ==  "Weekly report"
  last_email.to[0].should == 'user@email.com'
end

# Failure/Error: deliveries.size.should == 1
#   expected: 1
#        got: 0 (using ==)
```

my test env is correctly configured:
  `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`

And the WeeklyReport test is working fine:

```
  it "should send weekly report correctly" do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create_list(:user)
    email = WeeklyReport.weekly_report(@user).deliver
    deliveries.size.should == 1
  end
```

Why the controller test is failing?

**Edit 1:**
I noticed that emails are actually being delivered (real emails), ignoring the config: config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test - what could it be?

**Edit 2:**
My test.rb file:

```
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = false
  config.serve_static_assets  = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'dev.mydomain.com' }
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
```

Comment: what error are you getting in terminal?

Comment: no error, only test failing message: Failure/Error: deliveries.size.should == 1
   expected: 1
        got: 0 (using ==)

Comment: Check if your `current_user` is set and with all the required fields. It seems your mailer is silently failing. On a side note, even if it helps you solve your problem, I completely discourage you testing it this way due to code duplication.

Comment: I just noticed that emails are being really sent, ignoring the config: config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test - what could it be?

Comment: are you 100% sure that it is ignoring your setting ? `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test `

Comment: no... but the email is being sent, instead of added to fake delivery array, because emails arrive in my gmail inbox

Comment: can you include `config/environments/test.rb` in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said, it is not using your `test` setting, then there must be the problem with something with environment. Try explicitly setting it before it loads the specs and test it.

```
it "should send mail" do
  ::ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
  get :invite

  response.should redirect_to "/partners/index"
  request.flash[:notice].should eql("Mail sent!")

  ::ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size.should == 1     
  last_email.subject.should ==  "Weekly report"
  last_email.to[0].should == 'user@email.com'
end
```

Comment: Your answered solved the problem, and helped me to find where I was making a mistake: I had an mail.rb initializer with this line: ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp - GOTCHA!